# How could I prevent bind log write to /var/log/message

Tags: logging, dns, bind, named

I am using BIND 9.7 and there are too many bind error messages written to the log in `/var/log/message`.

Such as:

```
Oct 12 22:39:39 my-client-1 named[6360]: error (network unreachable) resolving images.uglyas.com/A/IN: 2400:cb00:2049:1::adf5:3a8c#53.
```

I want to prevent this message from being written to `/var/log/message`.

It makes my `/var/log/message` become too large.

Though I can use logrotate to control log size I would prefer to prevent the error from being logged.

Answer (score 0):

What distribution are we talking about?

If using rsyslog it should be enough to create /etc/rsyslog.d/20-bind.conf and add something like this:

```
:msg, contains, "named" -/var/named/named.log
& ~
```

And restart rsyslog